# How can i create Dataframe by different - different lengths of data

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, dataset

I have some rows of data in a list which values different -

```
x  7
y  7
base_price 28
entry_price  784
exit_price  784
high  784
strike  784
option_type  784
expiry  784
time  784
Gap  784
sl_exit_price  3136
pnl  3136
boolean  3136
```

these all number of values made by (values * 4), you can see the difference between values is the multiplication of 4.

here all these numbers are lengths of lists.
I want to convert them into a data frame but I don't understand how can I convert these?
I tried some ways but I get same error - `list index out of range`

So I want out put just like that -
Note - I'll explain dataframe here length of number of values.

Output -
[image]

Comment: `x` and `y` have a very small amount of values compared to the other columns. Do you want the `x` and `y` values to repeat for all the values in the other columns.

Comment: Yes. I want to repeat X and Y values for others, columns.

Comment: and 784 numbers of values and X and y numbers of values are the part of 3136 values.

Comment: Then please add a sample of the dataframe's contents to the question.

Comment: @user17242583 it is very hard to create a sample dataframe for it.

Comment: Could you just send the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Comment: I want to create dataframe, so how can I send you output? my dataframe isn't ready yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239456/discussion-between-krishna-gupta-and-user17242583).